# seaborn multiple boxplot based on multiple assignments

Tags: pandas, seaborn, boxplot, melt

Hello I have a dataframe that's assigned with two labels `sample` and `campaign`:

```
import numpy as np
var=np.random.sample(4)
sample = [1,1,2,2]
campaign = [1,2,1,2]
d = pd.DataFrame([var, sample, campaign]).transpose()
d.columns = ['var','sample','campaign']
```

and I want to plot the two `campaign` boxplots side by side with `var` as the y-axis, `sample` as the x-axis.
[image: see here]

Any idea how I can do this with `seaborn`? I am unsure how to manipulate the dataframe using `pd.melt`.. Or any other suggestion?

Cheers

Comment: The third example in the seaborn docstring does exactly this http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot

Comment: Sorry I've been staring at the screen all day. spent an hour manipulating pd.melt for some reason. Thanks !